# How to set the parameters to test form POST using WebTestClient

Tags: forms, spring-webflux, spring-test

How do I test POSTing a form using [`WebTestClient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/WebTestClient.html). How do I set the request parameters?

Using the non-reactive [`MockMvc`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html) I could use `.param()`, but `WebTestClient` does not seem to have anything similar.

Comment: I am answering my own question, [as is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [`BodyInserters.fromFormData()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyInserters.html#fromFormData-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) to prepare the [`body`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/WebTestClient.RequestBodySpec.html#body-org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserter-) of the request

```
   @Autowired
   private WebTestClient client;
   private WebTestClient.ResponseSpec response;

...

      response = client.mutateWith(csrf()).post().uri("/login")
               .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
               .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("username", player)
                        .with("password", password))
               .exchange();
```